# Makefile: set the environment variables output by a command

Tags: shell, makefile

I am trying to write a make target, where it sets the env. variables obtained by a shell command.

[gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) command on the terminal output few exports statement like (doesn't set, but just echoes / prints).

```
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8432
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id
```

Normally, I have to copy and paste these lines into the terminal to set the variables.

Is it possible to make these printed export statement to execute so they will be set on the shell. I tried like, but didn't work.

```
target:
    @export JAVA_HOME=$(JAVA_HOME); \
    $(shell gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init); \
    go run src/main.go
```

it prints out the script output if I do like,

```
target:
    export JAVA_HOME=$(JAVA_HOME); \
    gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init \
    go run src/main.go
```

Similar to the `JAVA_HOME`, how can I also source output of `gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init` command (which are 4 lines of export commands) so they are set in the environment.

so I want something like, in effect,

```
target:
        export JAVA_HOME=$(JAVA_HOME); \
        export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8432 \
        export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id \
        go run src/main.go
```

thanks.
bsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output printed by `make` does not actually affect the environment contents of subprocesses.

If the variable assignments do not appear to have any effect, that's because make runs each line in a separate subshell, each with fresh environment.  You need to join the commands together like this:

```
target:
    export JAVA_HOME=$(JAVA_HOME); \
    eval "$$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)"; \
    go run src/main.go
```

The `eval` is necessary so that the output of the `gcloud` command is evaluated in the current shell, and not a subshell.  Also note the semicolon at the end of the second line of the recipe.

Comment: so I tried like, ```  target:
    @export JAVA_HOME=$(JAVA_HOME); \
    gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init \
    go run src/main.go``` but still the env. variables printed by `gcloud` command is not set.

Comment: sorry I might have word it wrong. Edited the question slightly to clarify.  It is not to trace, but to set (export) the variables print by the command (gcloud beta ...). So the output of the command is 2 export statemens (which just prints to the console, but doesn't set). I want to set those variables and then start a command on the next line (same shell). I don't mind setting it at makefile level, but that env variable only available just before I execute the target. is it possible to evaluate the command just before executing the target. thanks for the help.

Comment: thanks you so much. I failed to see your edit initially :-) and it works great. thanks again for your time.